# Are "ValueNotifier" + "ValueListenableBuilder" suitable for "many" widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

A [`ValueNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) can be combined with one or several [`ValueListenableBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) to manage state and ease the development of UI.

However, `ValueNotifier` inherits from [`ChangeNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html), and the documentation states that:

> `ChangeNotifier` is optimized for small numbers (one or two) of listeners. It is O(N) for adding and removing listeners and O(N²) for dispatching notifications (where N is the number of listeners)

So, from what I understand, it's not best practice to have multiple `ValueListenableBuilder` listening on the same notifier.

On the other hand, [the official video presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-ZG-jS5QHQ) indicates on the contrary that you can update many widgets at the same time:

[image: Many widgets]

My questions would be:

- Isn't there a contradiction between the documentation and the video?
- Why are notifications O(N²) and not O(N)?
- Should I use something better than `ValueNotifier` / `ValueListenableBuilder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the complexity of notification:

Reading the [source code for ChangeNotifier](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/27321ebbad/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart#L99) look at the `notifyListeners` method: on line `203` a `for` loop is executed and for each iteration `_listeners.contains` gets called.

Both `for` and `contains` have O(N) complexity, and since `contains` is called at each iteration, there you have why it's O(N²).

I think that there's no contradiction between the video and the documentation. 
This approach is great for small situations, when you need to update few widgets according to a `ValueNotifier`'s value.

For a bigger situation you could use `InheritedWidget`, which I believe is suited to expose values even in an app-wide context (see Theme, MediaQuery), or you could use a BLoC approach, which leverages Dart streams.

Though I have searched, I have not found specific information on notification complexity for the suggested approaches.

I'm suggesting them as I think they're better suited for complex scenarios and I can back this by my personal experience using them.

Generally I use BLoC for business logic related state management and InheritedWidget (specifically with the [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)) for UI related state management.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is the commit which introduced the O(N²) complexity: [`b00efda`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/b00efda7fc0b6df84e7063c1551c42f37709c4db) (allowing listeners to be removed during notification). I'm using BLoC too, but I'm learning how to manage UI state (not involving business logic), that's why I tried to use `ValueNotifier`. I may switch to `provider` as it is officially recommended.

Comment: One last thing I don't understand: you suggest to use `InheritedWidget` but I fail to see how it would help regarding notifications. As far as I know, this widget helps with sharing "access" to the `ValueNotifier` object, but supposing I want 3 different widgets to be rebuild on value change, I still need 3 `ValueListenableBuiler`  which does not solve the complexity issue, right?

Comment: No, you wouldn't need `ValueListenableBuilder` in case of using `InheritedWidget`. Note that when you implement your own `InheritedWidget` you have to override `updateShouldNotify`: this method returns a bool which gives answer to this question: "Shall widgets holding references to this `InheritedWidget` be rebuilt upon changes?" If your override returns true, the referencing widgets will be rebuilt. 
Here's the doc for the mentioned method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget/updateShouldNotify.html

Comment: flutter changed the implementation of ChangeNotifier